# ui-routing doesn't load an init function on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an app where I implement page navigation with `ui-routing`. The first version of the app looks as follows:

Login page verifies and authenticates users and once approved, a user is routed to a welcome page with a single button - "click to view images" (images that are relevant to that specific user). Once clicked, the button routes the user to a page where he/she can view images that are relevant to that specific user. I am doing so by triggering an `ng-init()` function which sends a REST call to the backend without any gesture from the user. This version works great.

In the current version, I realized that the welcome page is redundant and wanted to implement a routing directly from the login page to the image load page without any button click. In this case I had to trigger the REST call to the backend without any page in between. Problem is, NOTHING comes up. This time the `ng-init()` function doesn't fire. The page that comes after the login remains empty, no errors on the console, and I just don't understand what is wrong. It is as if the routing requires a page in between the login page to the actual app functions. When I load the "image-load" page independently of the login page (using the full path rather then the routing relative path), it does render the images. But it is when I go through the routing service that it stops working. So to sum-up, the independent web link works but the"disguised" routing link does not.

The one thing I did realize, is that the .js page that contains the controls for the image loading page is not even being read, even though it is specified correctly in the html page. here are the relevant pieces of code:

app.js (routing):

```html
function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            /*.when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeController',    
                templateUrl: '../loginapp/home/home.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })*/

            .when('/landing', {   //welcome page
                controller: 'GeneralController',
                templateUrl: '../html/landingpage.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

             .when('/load', {     //image load page
                 controller: 'HomeController',
                 templateUrl: '../html/load.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })


.........
```

In the page that doesn't work, there is not much to show in terms of code. Everything is simple (and does work when not linked to the router) I basically declare a controller on my html page and call the `ng-init()` function through it..

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using $location.path('/landing') in your login controller?